# Sefer that discusses types of punishments in Gehenom?

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, gehinnom

I am looking for the name of the sefer that discusses the types of punishments given in Gehenom?

It's an old sefer and I can't remember the name.

Comment: The first Toldos Aaron rebbe, R’ Aron Roth in his sefer Shomer Emunim chelek 2, has about 30 pages on the topic. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35118&st=&pgnum=76

Comment: I think Rav Saadya Gaon describes it in Emunos v'Deos.

Comment: reishis chachma shaar yirah is the best

Comment: I think the גר"א discusses in אבן שלמה and his פירוש on משלי.

Answer (score 1):

Collating answers from the comments in addition to my own:

1. @Chatzkel suggests that the "The first Toldos Aaron rebbe, R’ Aron Roth in his sefer [Shomer Emunim chelek 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35118&st=&pgnum=76), has about 30 pages on the topic."
2. @N.T. suggests "Rav Saadya Gaon describes it in Emunos v'Deos." - [המאמר התשיעי: בגמול ובעונש בעולם הבא](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/kapah/9-2.htm)
3. [מעשה דרבי יהושע בן לוי](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_A_Tale_of_Rabbi_Yehoshua_ben_Levy%2C_Letter_of_Rabbi_Yehoshua_ben_Levy?lang=bi)
4. [מסכת גיהינום](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_The_Garden_of_Eden%3B_Gehinnom%2C_The_Book_of_Gehinnom.3?lang=bi)
5. [גדולת משה](https://hebrewbooks.org/36305)
6. [כיצד דין הקבר](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_The_Garden_of_Eden%3B_Gehinnom%2C_The_Judgment_of_the_Grave.3?lang=bi)
7. Chapter 12 and 13 of the Gate of Awe in R. Eliyahu de Vidas' [ראשית חכמה](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14032&st=&pgnum=63)
8. The Ramban addresses this topic in [שער הגמול: העונש והגהנם](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hagmul/4-4.htm)
9. The last מחברת of [מחברות עמנואל](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/11766) is התופת והעדן which parallels Dante's Inferno (you can read more about it [here](https://digitaldante.columbia.edu/history/immanuel-of-rome-and-dante-levy/)).

Regarding this last suggestion @N.T. wishes to point out that R. Yosef Karo maintained that this work ought not be read (see SA:OH 307:12), however others such as the Ramhal praise it and its author and it is similarly cited by R. Yehudah Aryeh mi-Modena, R. Eliyahu Behor, and the Yashar mi-Kandia (for discussion [see here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=12005#p113133)). It is also worth pointing out that the liturgical poem Yigdal is likely an adaptation from this work (fourth chapter). As a question of personal practice, consult a competent halakhic authority.

Comment: I deleted the reference to Sefer Emmanuel because he just copied Dante. In fact, the Shulchan Aruch OC 307:12 forbids people to read that work at all, and says Emmanuel was someone who caused the public to sin. See TB Rosh Hashana 17a, for the severe implications of that statement.

Comment: @N.T. I am rolling it back and editing to include a caveat.

Comment: Fair enough. Ramchal praised his poetic skills, not necessarily his views.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to Minchat Yehuda, by the great mekubal Yehuda Pitaya, which describes everything that happens to a Jewish soul after 120 years. It has also been published [in English translation.](https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Yehudah-Petaya-1859-1942/Minhat-Yehuda--Rabbi-Yehuda-Fetaya-English__p-202-11102.aspx)

Comment: There are way too many sefarim to get through these days. Baruch Hashem

Comment: To have such problems is indeed a bracha :), @RabbiKaii